# Syntax error when calling a stored procedure. I can't see what the problem is

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado

I am having trouble calling the following stored procedure.  When I call ExecuteReader, I am getting the error 'Incorrect syntax near 'GetAverages2'.  I can create the stored procedure and call it from TSQL.  I can't seem to get it working from ADO:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAverages2
    @CompanySize INT,
    @Q1         FLOAT OUT,
    @Q2         FLOAT OUT
AS  
    SELECT @Q1 = 1, @Q2 = 2
GO

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetAverages2", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@CompanySize", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["CompanySizeId"]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Q1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Q2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SqlCommand.CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) defaults to CommandType.Text, so it's trying to execute the text "GetAverages2" as a raw SQL statement. Add this line just after you create the command:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: I just fell into the same trap. I'm so used to using stored procedures, I can't imagine writing raw SQL. FYI, in SQL 2008 the error message returned in this scenario has changed to "Procedure or function '<proc name>' expects parameter '<param name>', which was not supplied".